# Laravel 5.2 - Using SetIdAttribute() Mutator To Set Other Value

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am currently creating a blog where each **Post** row in my database will have a unique **hash** attribute that is based of the post's id (incrementing, always unique).

This my Post model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Hashids;

class Post extends Model
{
  public function setTitleAttribute($value)
  {
    $this->attributes['title'] = $value;

    if (! $this->exists) {
      $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($value);
    }
  }

  public function setIdAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['id'] = $value;
    $this->attributes['hash'] = Hashids::encode($value);
  }
}
```

When I run this factory

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence(mt_rand(3, 10)),
        'content' => join("\n\n", $faker->paragraphs(mt_rand(3, 6))),
        'author' => $faker->name,
        'category' => rand(1, 20),
    ];
});
```

The **setIdAttribute($value)** function is getting called, but my hash attribute is not being set. I am not sure if it is getting overwritten or what.

If I move the line

```
$this->attributes['hash'] = Hashids::encode($value);
```

to the function

```
public function setTitleAttribute($value)
```

and encode the title attribute it works fine, but I want to encode the 'id' attribute. Any idea how I would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following to your model:

```
/**
 * Events
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($model)
    {
        $model->hash = Hashids::encode($model->id);
        $model->slug = str_slug($model->title);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the model to this ( http://i.imgur.com/ivZFYCy.png ), and now the hash and the slug are not being set

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to add $model->save(); to the end of the assignments

Answer (score 1):

It's likely `setIdAttribute($value)` isn't being called until after the insert runs because it doesn't know the ID until then.

The real issue is you can't set a hash of the `id` in the same query because the `id` isn't going to be known (assuming it's auto_incrementing) until after the insert.

Because of this, the best you can probably do here is fire some code on the model's `saved` event.

In that model, you can probably do something like...

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::flushEventListeners();  // Without this I think we have an infinite loop
    static::saved(function($post) {
        $post->hash = Hashids:encode($post->id);
        $post->save();
    });
}
```